# how to solve unsafe reflection issue reported by fortify

Tags: java, reflection, fortify

We are using reflection API to resolve the method calls

```
Object fData = method.invoke(srchFilterDTO, (Object[]) null);
```

The `srchFilterDTO` object comes from UI rest call as the input to `method.invoke()`.
So Fortify is complaining for unsafe reflection since the un-validated data(`srchFilterDTO` object) gets passed to `method.invoke()` call. I am not sure how to validate since its an object not string.

Basically I am looking for some suggestions to put the validation in place. Please Share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably some more detail is needed. However, you are saying that the instance of an Object is determined by a UI REST call. Do you mean the instance, or the type of object that's being instantiated? 
It would probably depend on the intended purpose of the program, but does the type of object need to be completely dynamic? Perhaps a whitelisting approach could be used to determine the type of object and reject any other. Alternatively, this may be either intended design of the application, or a design flaw. 
It's hard to say without further context of the program, so further explanation, such as where `srchFilterDTO` is coming from and how it's instantiated would be useful.

Comment: The srchFilterDTO is coming from JS layer as the ajax request. $.ajax({
         url :me.services.searchSubmit,    
         data:JSON.stringify(me.advsrchData.attr()),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         type: "POST",